# Disabling HTML Button in .aspx file not working

Tags: html, asp.net

I'm trying to write a script that disables a button depending on what the user entered on the previous page. However, I cannot even get the button to disable when I directly put disabled="disabled" into the input line. When I input the exact same code below on a .html page, it works fine and the button is disabled. I'm pretty new to web development, and I don't understand what's going on here. I specify `<!DOCTYPE html>` and the button is within the `<html>` tags. Any idea why this simple command wouldn't work?

```
<input type="button" id="b1" value ="How much can weight loss reduce my risk?" style="white-space:normal" disabled="disabled"/>
```

EDIT: All Code

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WebForm3.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication2.WebForm3" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet1.css" />
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #b1 {
            height: 137px;
            width: 137px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>


         <script type="text/javascript">
             google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
             google.setOnLoadCallback(init);

             function init() {
                 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                   ['Years Out Risk', 'Risk'],
                   ['5 Year Risk',  <%= TKR5%>],
                   ['10 Year Risk', <%= TKR10%>],
                   ['15 Year Risk', <%= TKR15%>],
                   ['20 Year Risk', <%= TKR20%>],
                   ['25 Year Risk', <%= TKR25%>],
                   ['30 Year Risk', <%= TKR30%>],
                   ['Lifetime Risk', <%= TKRLife%>]
                 ]);

                 var options = {
                     title: 'My Daily Activities',
                     'width': 400,
                     'height': 300,
                     animation: {
                         duration: 3000,
                         easing: 'out'
                     },
                     vAxis: { 
                         viewWindowMode:'explicit',
                         viewWindow: {
                             max:1,
                             min:0
                         }
                     }



                 };
                 var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                 var button1 = document.getElementById('b1');
                 var button2 = document.getElementById('b2');

                 function drawChart() {
                     button1.disabled = true;
                     button2.disabled = true;
                     google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready',
                         function () {
                             button1.disabled = false;
                             button2.disabled = false;
                         });

                     chart.draw(data, options);
                 }
                 button1.onclick = function () {
                     data.setValue(0, 1, <%= nobTKR5%>);
                     data.setValue(1, 1, <%= nobTKR10%>);
                     data.setValue(2, 1, <%= nobTKR15%>);
                     data.setValue(3, 1, <%= nobTKR20%>);
                     data.setValue(4, 1, <%= nobTKR25%>);
                     data.setValue(5, 1, <%= nobTKR30%>);
                     data.setValue(6, 1, <%= nobTKRLife%>);
                     drawChart();
                 };
                 button2.onclick = function () {
                     data.setValue(0, 1, <%= TKR5%>);
                     data.setValue(1, 1, <%= TKR10%>);
                     data.setValue(2, 1, <%= TKR15%>);
                     data.setValue(3, 1, <%= TKR20%>);
                     data.setValue(4, 1, <%= TKR25%>);
                     data.setValue(5, 1, <%= TKR30%>);
                     data.setValue(6, 1, <%= TKRLife%>);
                     drawChart();
                 }

                 drawChart();

             }

    </script>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>


    <input type="button" id="b1" value ="How much can weight loss reduce my risk?" style="white-space:normal" disabled="disabled"/>
    <input type="button" id="b2" value ="Reset risk" style="white-space:normal"/>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's not enough information contained in your request for someone to help you. You need to provide what you are doing in .aspx as well.

Comment: This is not a command, but a HTML tag attribute. Just by seeing what you've posted it's hard to guess what's wrong.

Comment: Post all of your code, one line is not enough to help you.

Comment: It's important to remember that inputs that are initially set as disabled server side CANNOT be enabled client side through javascript without posting back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using 
    < asp:Button id="b1" Text="Submit" disabled="disabled" runat="server" />

Comment: Thank you. This solves the problem, but creates a new one. When the ASP button is clicked (in the event that I don't want it to be disabled), the page does a postback. I don't want this to happen, as it generates an error due to the sql query I have in the code behind.

Comment: Actually I figured it out. I added return false; to the command my button executes and everything works as I hoped. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

if your button is `HtmlButton` you can try with

```
myBtn.Attributes.Add("disabled","disabled");
```

it work for me.

Comment: Did the job for what I was looking for.

Comment: perfect answer for html button (not asp.net button)